# Include executed cron command when outputting to log

Tags: bash, logging, cron

Is there a way I can include the command that was executed in the output when I'm logging to a file?
For example:

```
* * * * * date && /path/to/php /path/to/script.php >> cron.log 2>&1
```

Gives me:

```
Wed Oct  2 14:56:50 PDT 2013
output from script
```

How can I include the executed command too, to make the log look like this:

```
Wed Oct  2 14:56:50 PDT 2013
/path/to/php /path/to/script.php
output from script
```

I'm looking to add this in the crontab and not in the script.

Comment: Why not something like `* * * * * bash -c 'set -x; date && ... ' >> cron.log 2>&1`?

Comment: @Zoredache, excellent idea, you should provide that as an answer. You can add the -x option to the bash command: `bash -xc 'date && ...'`

Comment: Does someone want points for this? :)

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly putting together the excellent points of [@Zoredache](https://serverfault.com/users/984/zoredache) and [@Glenn](https://serverfault.com/users/30957/glenn-jackman) in comments, you can wrap your `cron` command inside `bash -xc` like this:

```
* * * * * bash -xc 'date && ... ' >> cron.log 2>&1
```